# How to play DVDs in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, dvd

Ubuntu is unable to play DVDs.
I used `regionset` to change the region.
`libdvdcss` (the newest version) is installed.
I enabled the option "No DVD menus" in VLC, and it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04 type in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
```

After installing `libdvd-pkg` you must run this command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

This should allow DVD Playback

If you're still having trouble, most likely the [region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_code) of your device is not set properly (or at all). Install `regionset` by typing

```
sudo apt-get install regionset
```

and then run

```
regionset
```

Comment: I typed and got this: libdvd-pkg is already the newest version (1.4.0-1-1).

Comment: After installing libdvd-pkg you must run this command - `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg`

Comment: This answer is correct according to the official documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs . You may want to check the region set part of the document and/or install *ubuntu-restricted-extras*.

Comment: Unfortunately the ubuntu help page is a bit sparse about what to do - "Follow libdvd-pkg's instructions to let it download, compile, and install libdvdcss. "  So many users miss the instruct to run that command as the instructs are 'twofold'. Someone should just edit the help page to be more explicit..

Comment: This is the [recommended way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) of installing also for Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install few codecs required specifically to play DVDs comfortably. These are:

- `libdvdcss2`: to recognize DVD
- `libdvdread4`: to read DVD
- `libdvdnav4`: to navigate DVD

**Step #1 Install `libdvdcss2`**

Since medibuntu is no longer available, you have to install `libdvdcss2` manually from VLC repositories :

```
wget http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/libdvdcss2_1.2.13-0_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libdvdcss2_1.2.13-0_i386.deb
```

**Step #2 Install `libdvdread4` and `libdvdnav4`**

Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4 libdvdnav4
```

Comment: I followed the instructions, but got this: libdvdnav4 is already the newest version (5.0.3-1).
libdvdnav4 set to manually installed.
libdvdread4 is already the newest version (5.0.3-1).

Comment: @Liso  Isnt' that for [Ubuntu 12.04 - Ubuntu 15.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs#Ubuntu_12.04_up_to_15.04_.28i386.2C_amd64.29)?

Comment: Somehow its working on my 16.04 machine

Comment: This is more correct of the answer.  `libdvd-pkg` only installs `libdvdcss-dev` and `libdvdcss` which are only used for decrypting discs.  There is a chance, and I know that VLC does not have the ability built in to read the discs until you install `libdvdread4` and `libdvdnav4`.  There might be distros that have these already installed, but I believe that it is against the license agreement to have `libdvdcss` installed by default.

Comment: OK, upon further reading, they don't include `libdvdcss` due to fears from some DMCA style laws.  There are other Linux distros that have it installed, but not Ubuntu by default.