# cdrom not identified by ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dvd

I have a dual boot with win10 and Ubuntu 16.04. The cdrom works fine with windows but it is not even recognized in Ubuntu. I cannot even find an entry in the `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lshw -class disk`

I cannot find anything in the Disk Utility as well. Noting in `dmesg` as well.

How can i fix this?

Comment: is it a CD/DVD you wrote yourself?   does it work in multiple computers?

if you write but not close a cdr/dvdr(or rw), you can write all data, but haven't yet written the directory to the disc (it get written to the disc when you close the write process), thus can be read normally by the machine that wrote the disc|disk, but not another computer (or OS), ie. if written on windoze, that version of windows can read it - but not ubuntu or any other computer windoze (as they don't have the directory written to their HDDs ready to write to cd/dvd..)

Comment: Problem solved by following the solution here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/845205/how-to-play-dvds-in-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1