# Installing appropriate software to play DVDs

Tags: networking, software-installation, mount, dvd

I would like to **watch a DVD**.  However, I have run into difficulties. Here is what I have done so far.

1. started by following [these instructions](https://itsfoss.com/play-dvd-ubuntu-1310/)

   Specifically, here are the steps identified in that web page that I have followed

   ```
   sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
   ```

   pressed "ok" or similar to various routine sounding prompts

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
   ```

   **Result:**

   Step 1 does not seem to have worked as I don't think VLC media player is on my computer.  At least I don't see it when I click on the icon with the 9 dots in the bottom left of my screen (the tool the brings up the list of programs).  Also, when I insert the DVD and then I right click the DVD looking icon (the icon that comes up on the desktop) the closest appropriate program that I can find is "video player" but when I select that, that gives an error message.
2. Next, I followed some instructions on 
   [How to play DVDs in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845205/how-to-play-dvds-in-ubuntu-16-04).

   Regarding the first answer listed there, I seem to have already done something similar to the first part of that answer (the first 2 parts of that answer).  So, I skipped those steps.  I did do the steps related to the region code.  Next, I started to try the second answer listed.

   I tried this command,

   ```
   wget http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/libdvdcss2_1.2.13-0_i386.deb
   sudo dpkg -i libdvdcss2_1.2.13-0_i386.deb
   ```

   But, that doesn't seem to have worked.  A lot of the response that got generated by terminal, says `wget: unable to resolve host address`

   At the end, terminal says

   ```
   downloaded: 1 files, 43k in 0.1s
   ```

   It doesn't sound like it downloaded much in the end, so I am thinking that the steps in answer 2 have not been working so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libdvd-pkg` only installs the `libdvdcss` files required for decrypting the discs.

Also run the following to install the applications files needed for browsing the discs:

```
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4
```

Then you should just be able to install the VLC Player:

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

I like to install everything that VLC has, so I run this:

```
sudo apt install vlc*
```

You can also install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` that gives you more encoders and applications for playing media:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```